# Use of Offset, Vlookup, and Concatenate to return a list

Tags: excel, vba, offset, vlookup, countif

On my "Pieces" sheet and table I have a bunch of IDs as follows:

```
Level ID    Tenant Type    Level SQM    Tenant
1358001     Retail              1000    VACANT
1358002     Retail              1000    Schoc
1358003     Retail              1000    VACANT
1358004     Retail              1000    Wishbone
1358005     Retail              1000    Zebrano Ltd
1358006     Retail              1000    Cranfields
1358007     Retail              1000    Astoria
1358008     Retail              1000    Mall Drycleaners
1358009     Unaccounted Area    1000    Unaccounted Area
```

I have then got a "front" sheet where the data is sorted etc.
I want to be able to list on the front sheet multiple tenants for a single level. In the example above all the Tenants are on the same level: "00".

On the "front" sheet I then pull up the Level ID I'm looking at in cell I30 by using `=CONCATENATE(F5,B15)`:`F5= 1358` : `B15= 00`.

Cell I32 contains: 
`=COUNTIF(pieces[Level ID],(CONCATENATE(I30,"?")))` which returns `9`.

Below this I want to make a 'dynamic' list of all the Tenants in level 00. I'm not completely sure how to do this (and I might be heading in the wrong direction) but I believe I have parts of the puzzle I just don't know how to piece it together.

I can return one Tenant with the following forumla:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(I30,"1"), pieces[[#All], [Level ID]:[Tenant]], 4, FALSE)
```

which returns the first tenant ("VACANT") correctly.

I was then thinking I could pull down a 'list' (just into the cells below) by using something like:

```
=OFFSET(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(I30,"1"),pieces[[#All],[Level ID]:[Tenant]],4,FALSE),0,0,I32)
```

which would use my `COUNTIF` statement to make a height of 9. However, this formula doesn't work and I can't manage to get it right, even after looking up a

Comment: So your Level IDs are text masquerading as true numbers...? If not, how is that VLOOKUP with CONCATENATE working?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes essentially, they have to be under text so I can use levels as 00 etc. Instead of just 0.

Comment: I don't know if this can be done with normal formulas.  Are you at all familiar with VBA?

Comment: @JamesFaix I've worked with VBA a little, but I'm still very new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to return the *first, second, third,* etc matching row numbers from the table to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(pieces[Tenant], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(pieces[Level ID])-ROW(pieces[#Headers]))/(LEFT(pieces[Level ID], LEN(I$30))=I$30), ROW(1:1))), "no more")
```

Fill down until you run out of matches. Change *"no more"* to a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) if you want the non-matching cells to appear blank.

[image: aggregate_next_tenants]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated

Comment: Just wondering if you know if it's possible to add a certain number (defined by a cell) of text boxes (or user forms or shapes etc) stacked underneath each other. Each shape/box/form could have the formula and other details in them. This would in a way remove the need for "no more". Possibly a cleaner solution than having zero-length strings in a worksheet etc

Comment: Formulas do not work that way; well actually, some [google-sheets] formulas do but not [excel]. With [excel] you need to fill the formula to the maximum number of possible matches. With VBA, you can dynamically change the number of returns but not with native worksheet formulas.